# find effective id euid for process with pid=<some number>

Tags: linux, process, ps, uid

How to find euid of a process if I know its pid
I tried
I get process id  using :

```
ps -f -u user1
```

then I tried `ps aux , ps -ef` with `grep pid` but can not see euid

I always try to get info from man pages but `man ps`  seems too confusing for a newbie like me.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the `ps` option: `-o euid`

Examples:

- Display a pid's euid

  `ps -eo pid,euid | grep YOUR_PID_HERE`
- Display a pid's euid, ruid and suid

  `ps -eo pid,euid,ruid,suid | grep YOUR_PID_HERE`